# Trying to understand advanced git branching

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I'm trying to play with Git branching in order to create feature out of the master, but I too often end up messing my git repository :/

I searched on Stack Overflow about what I'm trying to achieve, and often I can find how to merge/branch/revert/etc but not in the workflow I'm facing, which is, for me, what can happen quite often.

Here's what I would do as a workflow :

- Having a base project on master
- Creating a new branch, and working (create/modify, commit, push) on it
- Going back to master (or an other branch) and apply some modification (urgent bug fixes)
- Merging those changes from master into my current working branch (in order to reduce the conflits problems)
- Once done, merging my branch into master, ready to deploy !

Some of those actions seems easy, but the middle part (switching back, to master, apply change and then going again to branch) seems impossible to me :/

Here's where I am at :

(supposing the project is already on git, and some work has been pushed to master)

```
git branch feature
git checkout feature

# do some add/edit, commit, push on that branch

# Now I need to fix a bug in master :
git checkout master
# how can I get my files in the master state ?
# My best guest so far :
git revert HEAD

# do some add/edit, commit, push on master

# Finished to fix the bug, going back to continue my feature :
git checkout feature
# Again, how can I get my files to match the current state of the branch feature ?
git revert HEAD # And git asks me about a revert ? what ? I'm lost :/

# getting the recent changes from master into feature, in order to avoid later conflicts
# This can also be made often if you work with others
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/feature
git rebase origin/master

# do some add/edit, commit, push on master

# And when you have finish, merge feature into master :
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge feature
git branch -d feature # if you want to remove it.
```

This is my current supposed workflow, but I'm not sure `revert HEAD` is a good solution, and when I go back, this is more confirmed by Git that is asking me for a revert to the previous state that I have to push (?!).

Can someone help me clarify my situation and/or direct me to a great (but please, very simple) explanation to do what I'm trying ?

Thank you a lot, I really appreciate !

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout master` should already “get your files in the master state”.  The most common case where it fails is when you have uncommitted changes. But you could take care of that with `git stash`.  Or simply by committing to your feature branch, you can always cancel that one later.

`git revert` is intended to cancel commits you can't eliminate anymore (published history, for example), and works by creating an additional commit to undo its effects.  It's very different from the Subversion and/or Mercurial naming, and much less frequently needed.

Comment: That's odd because it didn't update my files (that's why I tried the revert then). I need to check more about it.

Comment: Is there something more missing ? Maybe checkout isn't enough, I need a pull/fetch/something to update the files to the master state ?